# This sloka is from which scripture? "आदित्यं गणनाथं..."

Tags: identification-request, shloka, reference-request

Looking for scriptural reference of shloka:

> आदित्यं गणनाथं च देवी रुद्रं च केशवम्‌।
>  पंच दैवत्यामि त्युक्तं सर्वकर्मसु पूजयेत॥

Comment: If satisfied with the answer, please press the tick mark sign near Mr. Ross’ answer. It means that the answer has satisfied your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book "Nitya Karma Puja Prakash" quotes this verse in the Deva Puja Prakaran chapter and attributes it to Matsya Purana but does not mention the specific location of the verse.

The said verse can be found on p.120 in [this PDF](https://satymarg.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/nity-karm-puja-prakash.pdf) of the aforementioned book.
Here is a screenshot from that page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to have come from any scripture directly, certainly not in any major Veda or Upanishad.

The earliest mentions I found were in compendiums of verses in Sanskrit, like the [Sabdakalpadruma](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sabdakalpadruma/f1wCkwnBI3AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%82%22&dq=%22%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%82%22&printsec=frontcover) and the They all quote the [Vachaspatyam](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Eleven_%C4%80tharva%E1%B9%87a_Upanishads_with_D%C4%ABp/nSnXjPmHrWgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%82%22&pg=RA1-PA171&printsec=frontcover), which is yet another compilation of verses. This seems to be the oldest text which references it.

My guess is that the verse was written *outside* of scripture and later quoted by rishis and swamis. That said, J.L. Shastri quotes it in his major translation of the [Shiva Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225964.html#note-t-88215). But it's in a footnote  (Shiva Purana 1.25):

> 60. One shall attain Rudra on seeing a person with Tripuṇḍra, his limbs covered with Rudrākṣa and repeating the Mṛtyuñjaya mantra
> 61. He is a favourite of the five deities* and a favourite of all gods. O beloved, a devotee shall repeat all mantras wearing a garland of Rudrākṣas (or counting on the beads).
>
> ---
>
> *The five deities referred to here are: the sun, Gaṇeśa, Goddess Durgā, Rudra and Viṣṇu.
>
> > ādityaṃ gaṇanāthaṃ ca devīṃ rudraṃ ca keśavam |
> > pañcadaivatamityuktaṃ sarvakarmasu (?) pūjayet ||